# Selecting for words nearest preposition (POS tagging)

Tags: r

I have a token and tag list and I would like to find all words (nouns and descriptive [adjectives and verbs] of those nouns) nearest a preposition. For example, in dataset below, how can I select for *glistening*, *oranges* and *rectangular*, *angular* and *table* (since these nouns and descriptors occur nearest the preposition, *on*).

```
 token <- c("Glistening", "oranges", "on", "rectangular", "angular", "table", "are", "delectable", ".")
 tag <- c("VBG", "NNS", "IN", "JJ", "JJ", "NN", "VBP", "JJ", "SENT") 
 data = cbind(token, tag)
       token         tag   
  [1,] "Glistening"  "VBG" 
  [2,] "oranges"     "NNS" 
  [3,] "on"          "IN"  
  [4,] "rectangular" "JJ"  
  [5,] "angular"     "JJ"  
  [6,] "table"       "NN"  
  [7,] "are"         "VBP" 
  [8,] "delectable"  "JJ"  
  [9,] "."           "SENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R approach, assuming that ....

1. window size of +2 and -2 around preposition
2. you have a list of prepositions

---

```
# Vectorize the seq function so that it accepts vector
seqvector <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

# Vector of prepositions
prepo <- c("on", "by")

# Find the matches
matches = grep(paste(prepo, collapse = "|"), data$token)

# Final unique rows to be selected
selectedrows <-
  unique(c(seqvector(
    from = matches - 2, to = matches + 2, by = 1
  )))[-(matches)]

# subset dataframe
data[selectedwords,]
```

---

```
# Output

       token  tag
1  Glistening  VBG
2     oranges  NNS
4 rectangular   JJ
5     angular   JJ
6       table   NN
8  delectable   JJ
9       hello SENT
```

---

```
# Data
token <- c("Glistening", "oranges", "on", "rectangular", "angular",
             "table", "by", "delectable", "hello")
tag   <- c("VBG", "NNS", "IN", "JJ", "JJ", "NN", "VBP", "JJ", "SENT")
data = data.frame(token, tag)
```